# How can I add images as labels on Titanium.UI.CreateButtonBar?

Tags: javascript, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

this is my code and I want to replace "start" "pause" and "stop" with images

```
var controlBar = Titanium.UI.createButtonBar({
        labels: ['START','PAUSE','STOP'],
         style: Titanium.UI.iPhone.SystemButtonStyle.BAR,
         backgroundColor: '#000080',
         top:10,
         width:200,
         height:40

      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`labels`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ButtonBar-property-labels) attribute can also be an array of [BarItemType](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/BarItemType)

```
var controlBar = Titanium.UI.createButtonBar({
    labels: ['START','PAUSE', {
        image : '/path/to/image',
        title : 'Title',
        enabled : true
    }],
    style: Titanium.UI.iPhone.SystemButtonStyle.BAR,
    backgroundColor: '#000080',
    top:10,
    width:200,
    height:40
});
```

Comment: Well! I am kind of late to my own question haha but just wanted to say thanks for the answer.It helped a lot